# Which is the best code using repository pattern for database context?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, dbcontext, dispose, using

I am implementing repository patter and I have a doubt about which code is better in terms of standards and good practices.

This is for an MVC 5 project I am starting, with repository patter in mind.

This is the first approach:
I am using a connstructor to set de db context and inside each method I use using

```cs
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private DBModel contextBD;

    public EmployeeRepository(DBModel contextBD)
    {
        this.contextBD = contextBD;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Add(Employee employee)
    {
        using (contextBD)
        {
            contextBD.Employee_Table.Add(new Employee_Table()
            {
                LLP_Id = employee.id,
                Name = employee.name,
            });
            await contextBD.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The second approach is this:
I do not use a constructor, and set the context in the using block

```cs
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public async Task<bool> Add(Employee employee)
    {
        using (DBModel contextBD = new DBModel())
        {
            contextBD.Employee_Table.Add(new Employee_Table()
            {
                LLP_Id = employee.id,
                Name = employee.name,
            });
            await contextBD.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which one will work better, which is the best practice and why, what are the benefits of unis one or another.

Comment: related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/10034

Comment: Check [this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/01/28/unit-of-work-repository-pattern-in-mvc5-and-web-api-2-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-ninject) out.

Comment: Neither, don't bother with a repository pattern, you're doubling your work for something that already exists. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/310866

Comment: @gilliduck I have the repository class because I separate some logic that don't need database operations and don't want to deal with the database in the logic layer, reading your suggestion it says it is not to bad to have this, if you think don't id like to hear you :-)

Comment: @gilliduck watching my code a hundred times make me understand your point, so I am possible adopting the DBModel as my repository and just using my service / logic layer to everything, any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, since you IoC inject it, you shouldn't wrap it in a using statement since this instance would be used by all methods for this call. (Assuming its IoC injected.)

While the 2nd option would work, you can't do any unit testing since it is now hard-coded.

I would recommend a third option.  I would inject a ContextFactory.  It would look something like this:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private IDBModelFactory factory;

    public EmployeeRepository(IDBModelFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory
    }

    public async Task<bool> Add(Employee employee)
    {
        using (var contextBD = factory.Create())
        {
            contextBD.Employee_Table.Add(new Employee_Table()
            {
                LLP_Id = employee.id,
                Name = employee.name,
            });
            await contextBD.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this case, the `Create()` method implementation would just `return new DBModel()` and now you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, with this I see I havve to add Factory Pattern with repository? I am right?

Comment: Kind of. I mean, its just that you send in the class used to create the Context instance instead of the Context itself.

Comment: Hi, I am trying  to apply your sggestion but I don not understand what is IDBModelFactory, can you give me a little explanation or guide please.

Comment: It is an interface. Put a method named Create() that returns DBModel. then create a class that implements it by just returning new DBModel().

Comment: Daniel, now  I understand your suggestion, I already implemented in some of my classes, I see if I have to change the context just need to modify the implementation of IDBModelFactory, that's right?

Comment: Exactly! Or if the configuration gets more complicated or you need async, you can do that too.